# Is it possible to use Google Apps for Work and host a website on the same domain?

Tags: g-suite

So this would mean using Google Apps for Work with http://example.com while hosting a website at http://example.com at the same time but not making use of subdomains.

If yes, what DNS records would this typically use? (generic examples are fine)

Assume the hosting provider permits editing DNS records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure - set your `MX` records for example.com to whatever servers GApps instructs you to use, and then configure an `A` record for example.com for the website.

Comment: Does that relate only to email? What about other apps like calendar, docs, hangouts, etc? Thanks. (I've never used Google Apps nor do I have an account so I am probably missing a lot of vital details).

Comment: You will be able to use all of the above with the records I mentioned.

Comment: I discovered there is a free trial so I tried it out. I thought the apps would be hosted somewhere on the user's domain but they are all hosted at Google.com (e.g. http://mail.google.com/a/example.com). Much simpler then I expected and the setup process was very well sign-posted by Google. Thanks.